# Equilibrium points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the Equilibrium points of the following system:
$$ u'=-uv$$
$$ v'=uv-v=v(u-1)$$
I would get considering $ u'=0, v'=0$:

1.$v=u=0$

2.$ v=0, u=1$

When I consider $$ H(u,v)=v+u-lnu \Rightarrow H'=H_u u'+H_v v'=0 $$
So I can conclude: $$v(u)=ln u -u +c$$

Then $v'=1/u -1 =0$
This would fit with 2.$ v=0, u=1$.
Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

$u' = -uv \tag 1$

and

$v' = uv - v = v(u - 1), \tag 2$

then

$u' = v' = 0 \tag 3$

yields

$uv = 0, \tag 4$

$uv = v; \tag 5$

from these two equations we find

$v = uv = 0; \tag 6$

the value of $u$, however, is unconstrained by (4) and (5); thus, the entire $u$-axis, where $v = 0$, consists of equilibria; there are no others.

Comment: I see, that means I found the right ones, but only two. As you said there are a lot more

Comment: The equilibria aren' stable, because, $$u\rightarrow  0  \Rightarrow v \rightarrow \infty $$ ?

Comment: @Leon1998:  actually, I think the equilibria are stable, based upon the Jacobean of the system.  The fact that $u \to 0 \Longrightarrow v \to -\infty$ refers to the non-equilibrium solution curves, not the equilibria, *I think*.

Comment: When you consider the Jacobean of the system: $J(0,u)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -u  \\ 0 & u-1   \end{pmatrix}  $, then the eigenvalues are 0 and u-1. How can you say something about stability?

Comment: @Leon1998:  I'll have to get back to you tomorrow when I wake up.  It's 12:30 AM here!  

Comment: Yes sorry for that. Have a good night:)